# how to affect previous and next images on image hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, transform

I have a problem that I could not solve, I  have this html where I want all the images to spin when I hover on one of them 
P.S: not all the images will have the same speed
here is HTML

```
<div >
<img id="first" class="pedal turnright" />
<div class="space"/>
<img id="second" class="pedal turnright"  />
<div class="space"/>
<img id="third" class="pedal turnleft"   />
<div class="space"/>
<img id="fourth" class="pedal turnleft"  />
</div>
```

I could manage to make the next images spin using ~ selector but not the previous ones
thank you in advance

Comment: Ok, what is the _exact_ question here?

Comment: There is no native CSS selector for 'previous'.  Your best option would be to apply your `:hover` to the `<div>` itself, as noted in the answer provided by @Jeremy Thille

Comment: thank you but I have some empty areas in my div and I do not want the images to spin when mouse is over these areas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all of the images inside a div to spin when you hover one of them, you don't need javascript for this. Apply some `:hover` effect to the div directly. You can tune each image's rotation speed :

```css
div:hover  img:nth-child(1){
       animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
   }
div:hover  img:nth-child(2){
       animation:spin 7s linear infinite;
   }
div:hover   img:nth-child(3){
       animation:spin 9s linear infinite;
   }
div:hover   img:nth-child(4){
       animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
   }


@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/80/80"/>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/80/80" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/80/80"/>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/80/80"/>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

if jQuery is an option, here's how to do it :

```js
var $imgs = $("img")

$imgs.hover( function(){
    $imgs.addClass("rotating");
}, function(){
    $imgs.removeClass("rotating");
});
```

```css
img{
margin-right: 50px;
}

img.rotating{
 animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/80/80"/>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/80/80" />
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/80/80"/>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/80/80"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have some spaces in div between image, I do not want the images to spin when mouse is over the empty areas

Comment: Okay, in that case, is jQuery an option ? Because it's easy with jQuery but a hassle in pure JS.